# Does Postfix recipient_delimiter take multiple characters?

Tags: postfix-mta, delimiter

According to this documentation, there is nothing stating if the delimiter can be multiple characters or a string.  Can someone confirm if it is possible to use a string as the delimiter?  Perhaps something like "-----"?

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_delimiter

Comment: I believe you can [configure different single-characters delimiters](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_delimiter), but cannot use multi-character delimiters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reading the source code it looks like that variable eventually gets used as an int. So the delimiter can only be a single character.

However, since Postfix 2.11, there can be multiple delimiters:

> When the recipient_delimiter set contains multiple characters (Postfix 2.11 and later), a user name or .forward file name is separated from its extension by the first character that matches the recipient_delimiter set.

Source: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_delimiter